# Dropbox oauth view is not rendering properly

Tags: oauth, electron, dropbox-api

I am building electron desktop app where user can grant access to his cloud drive using OAuth credentials. It used to work fine. Recently it is not rendering html properly. Eventhough user enters credentials, he is not able to submit form.

It is throwing below errors.

Please check the screenshot :
[image]

Adding another screen how submit button is disabled and user name and password text boxes are behind the view.[image]

**Electron process details :**
process.versions : 
ares: "1.10.1-DEV"
atom-shell: "1.4.14"
chrome: "53.0.2785.143"
electron: "1.4.14"
http_parser: "2.7.0"
modules: "50"
node: "6.5.0"
openssl: "1.0.2h"
uv: "1.9.1"
v8: "5.3.332.47"
zlib: "1.2.8"

Comment: Is is only happening in your Electron app? (E.g., does it work in a standalone desktop browser like Chrome?) If it's only happening in your Electron app, what browser/version is that using?

Comment: It is working in Web. Problem is only with electron version... It used to work before... Not working from last 15 days

Comment: See the added screenshot how view is disturbed

Comment: What browser/version specifically is used inside your Electron app?

Comment: @Greg check the update

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this in Electron, but I can't reproduce it in [Chromium 53.0.2785](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/403389/) itself, so it looks like this is specific to Electron itself somehow. Unfortunately, Electron isn't [officially supported](https://www.dropbox.com/help/3) by the Dropbox web site so I'm afraid this isn't something Dropbox will be able to fix.

Comment: Is there anything your team can help me with? This is very important business application we are working on. Any pointers look into ?

Comment: Electron isn't a supported browser, and it's working in the equivalent standalone browser, so I'm afraid this isn't something we likely can address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `BrowserWindow` has the `nodeIntegration` flag enabled by default. And this conflicts with the `RequireJS` implementation with which `Dropbox` was bundled.

Try to set `nodeIntegration` to false when creating a new `BrowserWindow`.

For more details, please check out my answer from a similar question:
[Dropbox oauth window is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124442/dropbox-oauth-window-is-not-working/47164045#47164045)