# Dropbox oauth window is not working

Tags: oauth, electron, dropbox-api

I'm porting my application to Electron and I was surprised to find out that the Dropbox authentication doesn't work in this environment. It does work in Chrome though.

The sign-in buttons remain disabled and the labels appear over the inputs.

The following message is displayed in the console:

> The Content-Security-Policy directive 'worker-src' is implemented behind a flag which is currently disabled.

[image: Console messages]

I'm testing using dropbox@2.5.7, electron@1.7.7 on OS X.

I found a similar question, but it seems to use a different version of Electron and has a different error message:

[Dropbox oauth view is not rendering properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049634/dropbox-oauth-view-is-not-rendering-properly)

---

**Update:**

The `Content-Security-Policy` message seems to be related to the Chrome version. The `worker-src` directive was introduced in Chrome 59 and electron@1.7.7 is shipped with Chrome 58.

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5922594955984896

I've tested with electron@1.8.0 that comes with Chrome 59, and the console messages are gone. But the problem with the auth page remains.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer here is going to be effectively the same [as I commented in the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049634/dropbox-oauth-view-is-not-rendering-properly#comment73333501_43049634). Electron isn't [officially supported for the Dropbox site](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/system-requirements), so it's unlikely to get fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `BrowserWindow` has the `nodeIntegration` flag enabled by default. And this conflicts with the `RequireJS` implementation with which `Dropbox` was bundled.

So the solution would be to disable `nodeIntegration` when creating the browser window:

```
const win = new electron.BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false
    }
});

win.loadURL(link);
```

Here's a small demo project:
https://github.com/kenjiru/electron-dropbox-sample-app